# Cannot get rid of overscroll in PhoneGap even with config.xml preferences

Tags: cordova, onsen-ui, overscroll

I'm fairly new to PhoneGap/Cordova and I'm trying to build an app for iOS and Android. I've read every page/forum I could find on how to get rid of the overscroll but it's just not working for me. I'm working with OnsenUI and AngularJS if that makes any difference. I have this in my config.xml file already:

```html
<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
<preference name="webviewbounce" value="false" />
```

I made sure I only have one config.xml in my project. The Cordova version is 3.5.0.

My navigation bars keep scrolling out of view because of this. Anyone tried anything else/have other ideas?

Comment: I had the same problem before but I do not think it was the overscroll that caused it. Maybe but maybe not. Did you check the .css part of it? I mean, I used to have a list in the content section under a toolbar, I also have a header within that content area but the header keep scrolling off view everytime I scroll the list content up. I had to use .css to lock the header in place. Without seeing the code or see what happens, it's hard to tell what's going on.

Comment: Sorry about the late reply! Can you explain what you mean by "lock the header in place"? Do you mean to give it an absolute position? I literally only have a view (`ons-page`) with a couple of images under a navigation bar. I can understand the page scrolling to see the rest of the images but it should not cause the navigation bar to scroll away right?

Comment: You're right. It shouldn't but without seeing the code, it's hard to tell what's going on. I have navigation bar everywhere on my app and it never scrolls off.

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution for this? I am in the same boat.

Comment: @human Unfortunately, I did not find a solution. And my team ended up switching from Cordova to Titanium Studio so I stopped trying to solve this issue.